# Select all times in a day in 12 hrs format based on current time

Tags: sql, asp.net

I need to select all hrs in day in 12 hrs format based on current time .ie if it is 03:00 PM I should get all the times between 03:00 PM and 12:00 AM .Any help will be really appreciated .Thanks in Advance

```
select distinct CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST( dateadd(hour,number-1,'01-jan-2017' ) AS TIME),100) as slots from master..spt_values where number>=1 and number<=24
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, YourDateField)) = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

Replace YourDateField with the name of your field